# how to set multiple pattern for one method in spring mvc controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "page/post/list";
}
```

I want url with pattern '/' or '/list' or '/index' are all handled by this method,is there any way to config it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/", "/list", "/index"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "page/post/list";
}
```